# For $Ax=b$ to have a solution, why should $x$ come from rowspace of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that the rowspace of an $m\times n$ matrix has vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the vector $x$ in $Ax=b$ also has $n$ components. However, I'm not clearly able to understand / prove why $x$ should be a linear combination of vectors in rowspace for $Ax=b$ to have a non-zero vector solution. Any help in developing intuition on this will be much appreciated.

[snippet of relevant text from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01ES6.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The logic in your question sounds _off_.  Are you asking why, given $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and a solution $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. $Ax_0 = b$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$), there will be some $x$ in the rowspace which is also a solution?

Comment: Thanks, may be a gap in my understanding, but let me try to clarify. In the text that I'm reading (Strang Linear Algebra), it says that the non-null solution to $Ax=b$ implies that x is in the rowspace of $A$. This is what I wasn't able to understand clearly.

Comment: If $A$ is zero matrix, then $Ax=0$ has tons of nonzero solutions. None of them is a linear combination of rows of $A$.

Comment: @VG If that is actually what it says, then it's wrong.  However, given its proximity to the alternative statement I gave, I'd worry there's some misunderstanding afoot.  I don't have the text to reference, though.  In case someone _does_ have it, can you give the edition and the page number?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I see. Maybe I am interpreting it wrong then (as it's a legendary book). Let me post exact snippets. Thanks for the help

Comment: What is true is that the coordinates of a solution are linear combination coefficients for column space. You can see it immediately when you write out row by row what $Ax=b$ means.

Comment: @AlvinL It's also true that it suffices to look for solutions in the rowspace, by considering  the orthogonal projection of an arbitrary solution.  That's what I'm thinking it might be.

Comment: @BrianMoehring attached an image of the relevant text

Comment: @VG It's possible I'm just tired, but I've read over that text twice now and cannot find which part you're referencing.  The closest seems to be the "Every vector $b$ in the column space comes from one and only one vector in the rowspace", but this is just a strengthening of what I said in my first comment.  It nowhere says the only solutions are in the rowspace; rather, in context it says the opposite: as long as $b$ is in the column space, there is a one-to-one correspondence between solutions and elements in the nullspace.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I think you're right, it was my mistake in understanding the text (late night brain fog). I think what the text implies is as rowspace and nullspace are orthogonal,  the vector $x$ can be written as xr + xn, and the xr component comes from rowspace. Thanks all for the help!